# CSS z-index with fixed positioning in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, z-index

I'm having big troubles making my page display both properly positioned and layered.

It's much bigger, but the basic layout is exactly the same as I created it here:
http://codepen.io/rjk/pen/AsGfm

Header and footer are fixed and do not move when the page content is scrolled around. What's really important is the *header*, whose structure is:

```
<div id="login-container">
  <button id="login-panel-button">Login</button>
  <div id="login-panel">
    <form id="login-form">
       ...
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

*#login-panel* is hidden when the page is loaded. Only way to bring it up is clicking *#login-panel-button*, which in addition blurs everything else (aside from *#login-panel-button*). I do the blurring by showing/hiding the fullscreen image of transparent black background *#background-blur*. And here comes the problem.

I want to blur everything else, but not the *#login-panel* and *#login-panel-button*. And so I have assigned *z-index: 1* to *#background-blur* and *z-index: 2* to *#login-container*. It took more than a while to grasp, why it doesn't work. The reason behind it is that Chrome creates a new stacking context for every element with *position: fixed*. *z-index* layering is relative, which means that the specified *z-index* value applies only in it's *stacking context* (the closest ancestor who created a stacking context himself or the root element). And so I specify *z-index: 3* of my *#login-panel* only in the *header's* context, which has it's default *z-index: 0* (it's like *#login-panel* having *z-index: 0.1*), and is displayed below *#background-blur* with *z-index: 1*.

Of course I could just raise *header's z-index* to *2*, but not when I want *#logo* to be blurred (displayed below *#background-blur*). Then I could create separate stacking-contexts by assigning *#logo* and *#login-panel* separately *position: fixed*, but I'd lose the ability to position them (on both sides) in a 800px centered container, which I need.

The problem is related only to Chrome. Try to run the pen I provided in Firefox and everything works like a charm.

For anyone wanting a good read, MDN has a nicely thorough article (with *stacking contexts* described in section 4):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: Details provided you are good, but you should consider to chop them off and come to the point... Users won't read that big chunk of explanation :)

Comment: if the login container is position fixed, why not just put it in the body rather than in the header

Comment: Pete, #login-container has position relative.

Comment: The only solution is to restructure the markup so the needed DOM elements are in the same stacking context.  Given that `position: fixed` elements are relative to the window regardless of whether they have a positioned parent this should be doable.  Also I agree with Mr. Alien, add a TL;DR at the end that summarizes what you are trying to do in a single clear sentence.

Comment: Yes but if you are blurring everything except the login panel - "Only way to bring it up is clicking #login-panel-button, which in addition blurs everything else", and the panel is relative to the fixed header (which in effect means it is fixed as the header is fixed), you may as well make it fixed and take it out of the header

Comment: Pete, true, but I want *#login-container* also to be relative to *#logo* (in a way that one is on the left and the other on the right side of 800px wide container). When I make *#login-container* fixed, I lose that ability.

Comment: see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DrvKx - it works in chrome the same as your other one does in firefox

Comment: Oh, I get it now. 2 fixed containers can be stacked on each other in the same position, so that they display as one, but each has it's own stacking context. That's just what I need! Big thanks, Pete! Oh, and you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the login container into it's own fixed position container within the body, you can give it the same dimensions as your header and it's own z-index so you'll be able to achieve what you want:

html

```
<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div id="login-container">
      <button id="login-panel-button">Login</button>
      <div id="login-panel">
        <form id="login-form">
          <label for="username">Username:</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></input>
          <label for="username">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" name="password"   id="password"></input>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <header>
    etc...
```

css

```
header,
footer, 
.center {
  width: 800px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header,
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

.center {
   z-index:2;
}
```

[Updated Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DrvKx)